# FileUpload Widget Issue in VS Code .ipynb: 'Upload(6)' Displayed, but data Length Returns 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

I was trying to upload a file using widget.FileUpload() and print the image out. But after uploading 6 images and trying to run the last line in a new cell it returned an error, saying "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
btn_upload = widgets.FileUpload()
btn_upload


img = PILImage.create(btn_upload.data[-1])
```

I then tried the line
`print("Number of uploaded files:", len(btn_upload.data))`
expecting "6" as that is the number of files I uploaded, it returned 0 instead.

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an image.